# Findroot: Boundary value problem

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, boundary-conditions

I have an equation,

```
ele[E2_] = -(1/(2 K3))
    L (E2^2 ea eo Sin[2 g[z]] - (K1 - K3) Sin[2 g[z]] Derivative[1][
      g][z]^2 + (K1 + K3 + (K1 - K3) Cos[2 g[z]]) (
      g^\[Prime]\[Prime])[z])
```

(* and parameters;*)

```
K1 = 12 ;
K3 = 19.5;
eo = 8.85;
ea = 14.5;
L = 1;
```

(*for E2= 2 the starting value is 6*)

```
nd = Map[First[
     NDSolve[{ele[2] == 0, g[0] == 0, g[L] == 0}, g[z], {z, 0, L}, 
      Method -> 
       "BoundaryValues" -> {"Shooting", 
         "StartingInitialConditions" -> { g[0] == 0, g'[0] == #}}]] &,
   {6}];
sl = Plot[Evaluate[{g[z]*(180/\[Pi]) /. nd}], {z, 0, L}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

(*for E2= 3 the starting value is 9.6*)

```
nd = Map[First[
     NDSolve[{ele[3] == 0, g[0] == 0, g[L] == 0}, g[z], {z, 0, L}, 
      Method -> 
       "BoundaryValues" -> {"Shooting", 
         "StartingInitialConditions" -> { g[0] == 0, g'[0] == #}}]] &,
   {9.6}];
sl = Plot[Evaluate[{g[z]*(180/\[Pi]) /. nd}], {z, 0, L}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

For (E2=1, the starting value is 1)

I cannot execute findroot to obtain starting values, so I can get the same output for E2 going from 1 to 30. By changing E2 from 1 to 30, the g will increase for instance E2=1,2,3,4 and stabilizes at 90 for E2=5,6,7.....

The output looks like the following for E2=3 and starting value 9.6.

[image]

When I copy the code back from stack to mathematical, it is giving some errors, so that's why the image with the infull code is attached.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

K1 = 12;
K3 = 195/10;
eo = 885/100;
ea = 145/10;
L = 1;

ele[E2_] = -(1/(2 K3)) L (E2^2 ea eo Sin[2 g[z]] - (K1 - K3) Sin[
       2 g[z]] g'[z]^2 + (K1 + K3 + (K1 - K3) Cos[2 g[z]]) g''[z]) // 
  Simplify

(* 1/520 (-1711 E2^2 Sin[2 g[z]] - 100 Sin[2 g[z]] g'[z]^2 + 
   20 (-21 + 5 Cos[2 g[z]]) g''[z]) *)
```

Use [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html) with parameters `E2` and `gp0`

```
pnd = ParametricNDSolve[{ele[E2] == 0, g[0] == 0, g[L] == 0}, 
  g, {z, 0, L}, {E2, gp0}, 
  Method -> 
   "BoundaryValues" -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {g[0] == 0, g'[0] == gp0}}]
```

[image]

Plotting the three cases

```
Plot[Evaluate[{(g @@ #)[z]*(180/π) /. pnd}], {z, 0, L}, 
   PlotRange -> All,
   PlotLabel -> 
    StringForm["E2 = ``, g'(0) = ``", #[[1]], #[[2]]]] & /@ 
     {{1, 1}, {2, 6}, {3, 9.6}}
```

[image]

To estimate the starting values

```
FindFormula[{{1, 1}, {2, 6}, {3, 9.6}}, E2]

(* -5.4 + 7.1 E2 - 0.7 E2^2. *)
```

Plotting `g` against `z` and `E2`

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[
  {g[E2, -5.4 + 7.1 E2 - 0.7 E2^2][z]*(180/π) /. pnd}],
 {z, 0, L}, {E2, 1, 3},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {z, E2, g}),
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]